# Unexpected output when I use BeautifulSoup for web scraping

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I don't know why my checkTargetExist function is returning the unexpected result.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def checkTargetExist(soup, id):
    errorDiv = soup.find(id)
    #if there is <div> which informs error message then my target does not exist.
    if errorDiv:
        targetExist = False
    else:
        targetExist = True
    return targetExist

# Create a BeautifulSoup object from your HTML content
html_content = """
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="errorDiv">We cannot find your search.</div>
  </body>
</html>
"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_content, 'lxml')

# Call the function to check if my target exists.
result = checkTargetExist(soup, "errorDiv")

# Print the result
print(result)
```

The code should print out `False`, but I get `True` from this code. Am I wrong?

Comment: [How To Debug Small Programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Take a look in the documentation:

https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-all

```
# is searching for <errorDiv></errorDiv>
errorDiv = soup.find(id)

# is searching for <tag id="errorDiv"></tag>
errorDiv = soup.find(id='errorDiv')
```